# Running django manage.py runserver under AWS doesn't work

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm prototyping a django web application on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance. I started an apache2 server and can serve a static 'hello world' html snippet that's visible from outside AWS, so I know that my http/https ports are open.

I stop apache, then run

```
sudo manage.py runserver 80
```

to get the example project running. Internal to the AWS instance, I run

```
lynx localhost:80
```

and I can see that runserver is operating properly.

For some reason, when I try to access the same site externally, I get HTTP102:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I tried to telnet to the ec2 instance to port 80, and got the same error. If I turn down the 'runserver', and bring up apache again, I can see the static website and port 80 is accessible again.

My question is: does apache do something to the AWS state other than listen to port 80? It doesn't make sense that I have port 80 opened externally, but only apache can accept external connections but django's 'manage runserver' does not.

Comment: Your apache is running on port 80 already so Django default port is 8000

Comment: To test, I took down the apache server, and I ran the django runserver on port 80.